# How to Make Dictionary from Diary Entries?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a regex for the date of a diary entry and, if matching, make the date the key and the subsequent entry the value.

First, I was going to just split into an array and make every odd index the key and every other the value.

Source https://archive.org/stream/AnneFrankTheDiaryOfAYoungGirl_201606/Anne-Frank-The-Diary-Of-A-Young-Girl_djvu.txt

```
file = open(r"C:\Users\mmcgown\Desktop\School\MSDS452\FinalProject\TheDiaryOfAYoungGirl.txt","r")
s = file.read()

import re
r = '(SUNDAY|MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY), (JANUARY|FEBRUARY|MARCH|APRIL|MAY|JUNE|JULY|AUGUST|SEPTEMBER|OCTOBER|NOVEMBER|DECEMBER) \d{1,2}, 19\d{2}\s*\n'
l = re.split(r,s)

l
```

However, that just splits before and after the regex. So splitting isn't the right approach...since it's also giving me the day and month for some reason also in the list.

```
'',
 'SUNDAY',
 'JUNE',
 'I\'ll begin from the ...
```

What's the easiest way to split these diary entries like the following?

```
{ 'SUNDAY, JUNE 14, 1942' : 'I'll begin from the ...' },
{ 'MONDAY, JUNE 15, 1942' : 'I had my birthday ...'},
etc.
```

P.S. I also tried the for line in file approach and it just kept getting uglier so I thought I'd seek input of the proper solution (I didn't finish the below).

```
file = open(r"C:\Users\mmcgown\Desktop\School\MSDS452\FinalProject\TheDiaryOfAYoungGirl.txt","r")
dia = {}
for line in file:
    i = 0
    if re.match(r,line) and i == 0:
        dia = {line.rstrip() : ''}
    elif not re.match(r,line):
        line = last_line + line
    elif re.match(r,line) and (i != 0):
        dia.update({line: last_line})
    i = i + 1
    last_line = line
```

Comment: Hi, why is the second approach so bad?

Comment: It would work using regex - your regex expression is bad. I'm not a regex pro so would need time to provide you the exact regex your need, but the reason it splits on days & months separately as opposed to finding it as a whole is because you're asking it to.

I would suggest working on getting a proper regex separately that works at detecting various combinations of complete/incomplete days/month/years and then worry about the res.t

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example (I used `OrderedDict` to keep the dates in dictionary in order, `sample.txt` is the text-file from your question):

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()

data = re.findall(r'^([A-Z]+, [A-Z]+ \d+, \d+)(.*?)(?=(?:[A-Z]+, [A-Z]+ \d+, \d+)|(?:ANNE\'S DIARY ENDS HERE\.))', data, flags=re.M|re.DOTALL)

d = OrderedDict( data )

from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
```

Prints:

```
OrderedDict([('SUNDAY, JUNE 14, 1942',
              '\n'
              '\n'
              '\n'
              "I'll begin from the moment I got you, the moment I saw you "
              'lying on the table among\n'

...till

          "what I'd like to be and what I could be if ... if only there "
          'were no other people in\n'
          'the world.\n'
          '\n'
          'Yours, Anne M. Frank\n'
          '\n'
          '\n')])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?(I didn't want to change your regex, so I used it)

1. Iterate through lines to find all lines indexes matching your regex, save these result in a list of tuples, when each tuples contains:**(your desired date, line index)**
2. Iterate through the result found above and add them to the
   dictionary(`dia`)

import re

from pprint import pprint

```
r = '(SUNDAY|MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY), (JANUARY|FEBRUARY|MARCH|APRIL|MAY|JUNE|JULY|AUGUST|SEPTEMBER|OCTOBER|NOVEMBER|DECEMBER) \d{1,2}, 19\d{2}\s*\n'
date_indexes = []
with open(r"your_file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if re.match(r, line):
            date_indexes.append((line.strip(), i))

    dia = {}
    for i in range(0, len(date_indexes) - 1):
        cur_idx = date_indexes[i][1] + 1
        next_idx = date_indexes[i + 1][1] - 1
        dia.update({date_indexes[i][0]: ''.join(lines[cur_idx:next_idx])})


pprint(dia)
```